# Random Astronomy Photo: React app using NASA's Astronomy Pic of the Day API

Tags: javascript, react.js, api, ajax

## Random Astronomy Photo

### About the project

This is a React app that generates a random photo from NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day (APOD) API along with some interesting facts about it. This is my first React app and my first major coding project that I did entirely on my own.

You can visit a live version here: https://jennifercadams.github.io/Random-Astronomy-Photo/

The GitHub repository is here: https://github.com/jennifercadams/Random-Astronomy-Photo

### Questions

I am open to any feedback you are willing to provide, but I am specifically interested in suggestions relating to:

- Improving the JavaScript to make it cleaner, more readable, and/or more concise.
- Improving the design to look more modern and professional.
- Could it be more user friendly and/or accessible?

Thank you so much for your time and for checking out my project!

### Code

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Generate random astronomy photos from NASA Astronomy Picture of the Day."
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Random Astronomy Photo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### index.css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #f0f0fa;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #131445;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#00009e, #131445);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

#### app.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { renderData } from './helperFunctions';

const apiKey = 'DEMO_KEY';
const url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?count=1&api_key=' + apiKey;

class App extends React.Component {
  getPhoto() {
    document.getElementById('info-box').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('more-info').innerHTML= 'More Info';
    document.getElementById('about-box').style.display = 'none';
    renderData(url);
  }
  toggleInfo() {
    if (document.getElementById('info-box').style.display === 'none') {
      document.getElementById('more-info').innerHTML = 'Hide Info';
      document.getElementById('info-box').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('about-box').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('more-info').innerHTML = 'More Info';
      document.getElementById('info-box').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  toggleAbout() {
    if (document.getElementById('about-box').style.display === 'none') {
      document.getElementById('about-box').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('info-box').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('more-info').innerHTML = 'More Info';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('about-box').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Random Astronomy Photo</h1>
          <button id="get-photo" onClick={this.getPhoto}>Get Photo</button>
          <button id="more-info" onClick={this.toggleInfo}>More Info</button>
          <button onClick={this.toggleAbout}>About</button>
        </header>
        <main>
          <div id="info-box" style={{display: 'none'}}>
            <h2 id="info-title"></h2>
            <p id="info-credit" style={{display: 'none'}}></p>
            <p id="info-date"></p>
            <p id="description" class="text-body"></p>
            <p><a id="img-link" href="" target="_blank">See full size photo</a></p>
            <p><a id="apod-permalink" href="" target="_blank">Permalink</a></p>
          </div>
          <div id="about-box" style={{display: 'none'}}>
            <h2>About This App</h2>
            <div class="text-body">
              <p>This app was made with love by jennsparkles. Data and images are from NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day API.</p>
              <p>Learn more:</p>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html" target="_blank">NASA Astronomy Picture of the Day (APOD)</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://api.nasa.gov/" target="_blank">NASA API portal</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <figure id='img-container'>
            <img id="photo" src="" alt=""></img>
            <figcaption id="caption"></figcaption>
            <p id="date"></p>
        </figure>
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### helperFunctions.js

```
const convertToPermalink = (date) => {
  let formattedDate = date.substring(2).replace(/-/g, '');
  return `https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap${formattedDate}.html`;
};

const renderImg = (imgSrc) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.getElementById('photo').src = imgSrc;
    document.getElementById('photo').onload = () => resolve('photo retrieved');
    document.getElementById('photo').onerror = () => reject('trying again');
  });
};

let retries = 0;

export const renderData = (url) => {
  let photoData;
  console.log('getting photo...')
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => photoData = data[0])
    .then(() => {
      let date = photoData.date;
      let credit = photoData.copyright;
      let title = photoData.title;
      let description = photoData.explanation;
      let imgSrc = photoData.url;
      let permalink = convertToPermalink(date);    
      renderImg(imgSrc).then((msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        document.getElementById('get-photo').innerHTML = 'New Photo';
        document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = title;
        document.getElementById('info-title').innerHTML = title;
        document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
        document.getElementById('info-date').innerHTML = date;
        document.getElementById('more-info').style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = description;
        document.getElementById('img-link').href = imgSrc;
        document.getElementById('apod-permalink').href = permalink;
        if (credit === undefined) {
          document.getElementById('info-credit').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('info-credit').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('info-credit').innerHTML = 'Credit: ' + credit;
        }})
      .catch((reason) => {
        if (retries < 3) {
          retries++;
          console.log(reason + ' ' + retries);
          renderData(url)
        } else {
          document.getElementById('img-container').innerHTML = 'Error: Can\'t get photo. Try again later.';
        };
    })
  })
};
```

#### app.css

```
header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 130px;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "main";
}

h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

figcaption, p, li, h2 {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

a {
  color: #f0f0fa;
}

a:hover {
  color: #acaccc;
}

button {
  background-color: #e1e1f1;
  color: #131445;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px #acaccc;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #acaccc;
  top: 2px;
}

#more-info {
  display: none;
}

#photo {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 66px);
}

figure {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 10px 40px;
  height: calc(100vh - 180px);
  grid-area: main;
}

#info-box, #about-box {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 5px 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 170px);
  background-color: hsla(217, 100%, 7%, 0.95);
  border-radius: 10px;
  grid-area: main;
  z-index: 1;
}

#info-box p, #about-box p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#description {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.text-body {
  text-align: left;
}

footer {
  height: 30px;
}

@media (max-height: 690px) {
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #photo {
    max-height: calc(100% - 52px);
  }
  footer {
    height: 20px;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  #info-box, #about-box {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px 10%;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  button {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jennsparkles, first off, congrats on making your first React app! I think the next step for you would be "componentizing" your app by using state, props, and composition (as an example, turning the header, info-box, about-box, and img-container into their own components). Have you learned about any of these topics yet?